# NSWindowController's window released immediately

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, automatic-ref-counting, nswindowcontroller

I'm trying to open a window using a NSWindowController in my app delegate.
I created a basic NSWindowController with an associated NIB and try to show the window that way:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Show the main window from a separate nib
    MyWindowController * theWindowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
    [theWindowController showWindow:self];
}
@end
```

When I launch the app, the window of MyWindowController only appears for a fraction of second (seems to be released as soon as it launches).

Using ARC, how could I force the window to stick around and not be flushed right away? I do not use NSDocuments and I want to be able to use many of these MyWindowController concurrently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a property to your app delegate (or some other object that's going to stick around for the lifetime of your app) that retains theWindowConroller. For example:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyWindowController * windowController;

@end
```

Then set this property when you initialize the window controller.

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Show the main window from a separate nib
    self.windowController = [[MyWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindowController"];
    [theWindowController showWindow:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: what if i want to open identical window with windowController? when i call second one first one released immediately. if i create windowController1 it works but i want to create more.

Comment: @mohacs You need to save every window controller you presents. Create new property for second one as well. Need to create even more? Create `NSMutableArray` and add them there too.