# New created viewcontroller from xib not responding

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xib, nswindowcontroller

I have following problem:

I try to build a small MenuBar App for MacOs. It is xib based and the main app is a MainMenu. From one of the menuItems I try to open a new NSWindow. I made a SecondViewController.swift with its generated SecondViewController.xib.

Simple View with one button:

[View of NSWindow as xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXi7e.png)

SecondViewController.swift
[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLQL2.png)

The button title changes to "ROFL", but when the button is pressed nothing happens. Cann someone explain this to me?

Here the controller is created:

[Init code of Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRMBS.png)

Comment: Post your code as text in the question please.

Comment: Is the button connected to the action (I usually forget)? Do you hold on to the window controller or is it released? (a `NSWindowController` constant named `…ViewController` is confusing btw).

Comment: Sorry for bad naming, I am more or less testing around. But yes the button is connected to a action. I checked it way to often. What do u mean with "holding the window controller" or "releasing it". Sorry Im pretty new to the whole framework

Comment: I can add more code as text if needed

Comment: ARC will release the window controller unless you have a strong reference to it. [NSWindowController's window released immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677043/nswindowcontrollers-window-released-immediately)

Comment: Okay, after knowing this, looks obvious. Thank you, it works now!